# kile and png graphics

Tags: png, kile

I am using kile as a latex editor with the latex compiler. With ubuntu 14.04 when I used \includegraphics to insert a png image I got the bounding box without doing nothing. I think that kile and imagemagick worked together to doing it.
With ubuntu 16.04 I have to look manually for the bounding box through gimp.

How could do to get again the bounding box through kile? Thanks